# Referencing the state leads to "TypeError: Cannot read property 'folders' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I want to add to a state array, but I find that any code I write that brings up the state leads to the same error one the browser tries to run it.

Even just a console.log triggers it.

```
var folderList = this.state.folders;
        console.log("folderList: " + folderList);
```

The full code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import {FontAwesomeIcon} from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import NoteListNav from '../NoteListNav/NoteListNav';
import NotePageNav from '../NotePageNav/NotePageNav';
import NoteListMain from '../NoteListMain/NoteListMain';
import NotePageMain from '../NotePageMain/NotePageMain';
import dummyStore from '../dummy-store';
import {getNotesForFolder, findNote, findFolder} from '../notes-helpers';
import './App.css';

import AddFolder from '../AddFolder/AddFolder';
import AddNote from '../AddNote/AddNote';

class App extends Component {
    state = {
        notes: [],
        folders: [],
        //noteID: 0,
        //folderID: 0
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        // fake date loading from API call
        setTimeout(() => this.setState(dummyStore), 600);
    }

    folderSubmit(f){
        console.log("folderSubmit ran " + f);

        var folderList = this.state.folders;
        console.log("folderList: " + folderList);

        //this.setState({ folders: joined })
    }

    renderNavRoutes() {
        const {notes, folders} = this.state;
        return (
            <>
                {['/', '/folder/:folderId'].map(path => (
                    <Route
                        exact
                        key={path}
                        path={path}
                        render={routeProps => (
                            <NoteListNav
                                folders={folders}
                                notes={notes}
                                {...routeProps}
                            />
                        )}
                    />
                ))}
                <Route
                    path="/note/:noteId"
                    render={routeProps => {
                        const {noteId} = routeProps.match.params;
                        const note = findNote(notes, noteId) || {};
                        const folder = findFolder(folders, note.folderId);
                        return <NotePageNav {...routeProps} folder={folder} />;
                    }}
                />
                <Route path="/add-folder" component={NotePageNav} />
                <Route path="/add-note" component={NotePageNav} />
            </>
        );
    }

    renderMainRoutes() {
        const {notes, folders} = this.state;
        return (
            <>
                {['/', '/folder/:folderId'].map(path => (
                    <Route
                        exact
                        key={path}
                        path={path}
                        render={routeProps => {
                            const {folderId} = routeProps.match.params;
                            const notesForFolder = getNotesForFolder(
                                notes,
                                folderId
                            );
                            return (
                                <NoteListMain
                                    {...routeProps}
                                    notes={notesForFolder}
                                />
                            );
                        }}
                    />
                ))}
                <Route
                    path="/note/:noteId"
                    render={routeProps => {
                        const {noteId} = routeProps.match.params;
                        const note = findNote(notes, noteId);
                        return <NotePageMain {...routeProps} note={note} />;
                    }}
                />
                <Route
                    path="/add-folder"
                    render={routeProps => {
                        return <AddFolder addNewFolder={this.folderSubmit}/> 
                    }}
                />
                 <Route
                    path="/add-note"
                    render={routeProps => {
                        return <AddNote/> 
                    }}
                />
            </>
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <nav className="App__nav">{this.renderNavRoutes()}</nav>
                <header className="App__header">
                    <h1>
                        <Link to="/">Noteful</Link>{' '}
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon="check-double" />
                    </h1>
                </header>
                <main className="App__main">{this.renderMainRoutes()}</main>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Did my answer work for you? Consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235) if that's the case.

Answer (score 1):

`this` will not be what you expect inside of `folderSubmit`. How to get around this is [discussed in the "Handling Events" part of the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html). You could bind it to `this` in the constructor, or use an arrow function as a class field.

```js
folderSubmit = (f) => {
  var folderList = this.state.folders;
  console.log("folderList:", folderList);
}
```